# Make Batch file to add special tags at the front of video files at one folder

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, powershell, batch-file, cmd.exe

I always make download for learning tutorials videos , Some times I don't remember where I can find those videos because they are too many , so I decide to make tags to those file and put them in front of any file ( e.g VLSH_ V stand for video , L mean Learn , S mean software , H mean hard drive)

to make this batch file I will start to make those steps

> 1 - find how many files at the folder
>
> 2 - save the files names to a variables or array of variables ( if
>   that allowed)
>
> 3 - use for loop to append VLSH_ as an example to the variables , then
>   rename the files with the new ones

can any one help me to make this batch , thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1: Use the Get-childitem command and wrap it for a .net syntax count command:

`(get-childitem .\*.avi).count`

This will give you the count of AVI video files in the current folder.

2 & 3: No need to create a variable list.  Loop like this:

```
Foreach ($f in (get-childitem .\*.avi)){rename-item $f.fullname ("VLSH_" + $f.name)}
```

This will rename each *.avi file in the current folder with the VLSH_ prefix.

Comment: thank you so much , It work , but can you make that from cmd , thank you again

Comment: I don't know about counting the amount of *.avi objects via CMD but I do know you can:    `rename *.avi VLSH_*.avi`

Comment: Here's another post about counting objects in a folder via CMD: [Count Objects via CMD](http://serverfault.com/questions/110725/windows-command-prompt-how-to-get-the-count-of-all-files-in-current-directory)